# asp.net login page details storage information

Tags: c#, asp.net

after creating asp.net page if we run that project it shows asp.net welcome

if we create a username and password and login the page.

after that if we want the users created their name and password where the data will be saved in project and how to check the login details.

Answer (score 3):

if you are using default template which comes with Visual studio then the data will be stored into aspnetDb.mdf under the App_Data folder. you can check it with explorer. for this also you need to have SQL Excpress edition  By default these template uses that ASpnetDb.MDF file for authentication data.

here is your sample Screenshot.

[image]

Comment: but how to open and check the data in them

Answer (score 0):

If you access your config file, you can find

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationServices"
         connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Nota : `AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.mdf` is path of your DataBase.

You can open your DataBase in Server Explorer

[image]